# Creating a menu that filters elements by year range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

okay, I want to make a filtering dropdown menu for my website.
here is what i got:

```
<select id="typeOption">
    <option value="all">all</option>
    <option value="type1">1</option>
    <option value="type2">2</option>
    <option value="type3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="yearOption">
   <option value="all">all</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type2" data-year-option="2018">content</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type1" data-year-option="2017">content</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type1" data-year-option="2016">content</div>
```

two select elements and a bunch of thumbnails that should be shown or hidden based on the selection.

and the following jquery:

```
var ChosenType = $('#typeOption').find(':selected').attr('value');
var ChosenYear = $('#yearOption').find(':selected').attr('value');


$('.thumbnail').css('display','none');
var selector = '.thumbnail';


if(ChosenType != "all"){
    selector += '[data-type-option="'+ ChosenType +'"]';
}

if(ChosenYear != "all"){
    selector += '[data-year-option="'+ ChosenYear +'"]';
}

$(selector).show();
```

this works so far. here comes the question though:
This only checks if the selected category matches a thumbnail exactly.
Basically what I want is an additional year select element and the first one should filter from the selected year forward (e.g. if you select the year 2010, all thumbnails that are 2010 and above should be shown) and the second one should filter up to the selected year (e.g. if you select 2010 all thumbnails that are 2010 and below should be shown), so that you can select a range of years that should be displayed.

thanks for any help!

Comment: So, do you want to add one more `<select>` and will have something like: starting year and final year, right? If not, so I didn't understand what you need. A snippet and an example of desired output would be nice

Comment: @Calvin Nunes yes exactly like that. basically like this here: http://damienhirst.com/artworks/catalogue

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop:

```
var yearStart = $('#yearStart').find(':selected').attr('value');
var yearEnd = $('#yearEnd').find(':selected').attr('value');


$('.thumbnail').css('display','none');


if(ChosenType != "all"){
    for(var i=yearStart; i<=yearEnd ; i++){
      var selector = '.thumbnail';
      selector += '[data-type-option="'+ i+'"]';
      $(selector).show();
    }        
}
```